# Using Dotfuscator with Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio

According to documentation, Dot Net Obfuscator (Dotfuscator for short) is pre-installed in VS Studio 2012.

It should be found at [Tools -> Dotfuscator Software Services](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=507).

However, no such thing is here:

[image]

Does Dotfuscator come installed default on Visual Studio 2012/2013 Express anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dotfuscator product is only included by default in non-Express SKUs of Visual Studio.  This is true for all versions of Visual Studio (to date 2010, 2012 and 2013)

IIRC the logic goes along the lines of Express can't be used to develop commercial products and there is little value in obfuscating hobby projects hence they aren't paired together